# RT audio Mac error g++ compiling error

Tags: c++, macos, compilation, rtaudio

Having problems getting rt audio to compile using simple application

```
#include "RtAudio.h"

int main()
{
        RtAudio *audio = 0;
        audio = new RtAudio;
        delete audio;
return 0;
}
```

to compile

```
g++ -Wall -D__MACOSX_CORE__ -o probe rtaudio.cpp RtAudio.cpp -framework CoreAudio -lpthread
```

error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "RtAudio::RtAudio(RtAudio::Api)", referenced from:
      _main in rtaudio-e456a2.o
      _main in RtAudio-a64f56.o
"RtAudio::~RtAudio()", referenced from:
  _main in rtaudio-e456a2.o
  _main in RtAudio-a64f56.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please post the error message that you get

Comment: sorry forgot to include that

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "RtAudio::RtAudio(RtAudio::Api)", referenced from:
      _main in rtaudio-e456a2.o
      _main in RtAudio-a64f56.o
  "RtAudio::~RtAudio()", referenced from:
      _main in rtaudio-e456a2.o
      _main in RtAudio-a64f56.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link your code with RtAudio library, so add `-lrtAudio` to your compile command:

```
g++ -Wall -D__MACOSX_CORE__ -o probe RtAudio.cpp -framework CoreAudio -lpthread -lrtAudio
```

And you have included two RtAudio, one "rtaudio.cpp" and two RtAudio.cpp, you should clear rtaudio.cpp, because you included `#include "RtAudio.h"` with uppercase in your main

Comment: thanks mate error has now changed to       duplicate symbol _main in:
    /var/folders/2_/5qkrtk5x6zg0k4pkk0qgk73h0000gn/T/rtaudio-9e7532.o
    /var/folders/2_/5qkrtk5x6zg0k4pkk0qgk73h0000gn/T/RtAudio-328ca3.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)